# Tish'a Ushloshim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirty-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yitzchak* was 139 at *Ever*'s death. Source: [*M'gila* 17a with *Rashi*](http://web.archive.org/web/20070816193605/www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_timeline.html).

Comment: Checkmark for the diagram.

Answer (score 3):

139 [were](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%91) the doormen of Ezra. (Fits the beat, sorta.)

Answer (score -1):

139 of the Forbes 400 are Jewish

Comment: Halachically? self-identifyingly? ethnically (whatever that means)? or what?

Answer (score -1):

ונחלמה = 139.....